# host is able to resolve a hostname, ssh isn't

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, ssh, resolv.conf

I'm trying to connect from a 10.04 system to a 12.04 system via SSH. Strangely enough the rules in `resolv.conf` seem to take effect only selectively, which leaves me puzzled. Observe:

```
[2] user@mach:~$ ssh pangolin
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pangolin: Name or service not known
[2] user@mach:~$ host pangolin
pangolin.subdomain.domain.tld has address 172.16.7.12
```

`subdomain.domain.tld` is on the `search` line in `/etc/resolv.conf` and using `host` the name is properly searched given those rules. However, with the SSH client `ssh` I receive the error reproduced above. How can this be? I was always of the impression that the name resolution rules in `resolv.conf` apply system-global.

Note: `/etc/hosts` doesn't declare the name `pangolin` at all. The package `openssh-server` is configured on the target machine. The question is purely about why name resolution isn't consistent between those two programs.

Another note: the command works fine when I enter the fully-qualified domain name, i.e. `pangolin.subdomain.domain.tld`.

Meanwhile I rebooted the client machine (10.04) and the problem still exists. A DNS caching daemon isn't installed, so I reckon that shouldn't have been a problem anyway.

---

The information asked for in the comment:

```
$ grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`, I transformed the domain names consistently:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.16.1.1
nameserver 172.16.1.5
search subdomain.domain1.com domain1.com domain2 domain3.com domain2.ccTLD domain3.net dev.domain1.com sdk.dev.domain1.com
```

... and the full `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

... and `/etc/network/interfaces`, which is the source for `resolv.conf` in 12.04:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.1.234
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 172.16.255.254
        dns-nameservers 172.16.1.1 172.16.1.5
        dns-search domain1.com. domain2. domain3.com. domain2.ccTLD. domain3.net. dev.domain1.com. sdk.dev.domain1.com. subdomain.domain1.com.
        dns-domain subdomain.domain1.com.
```

Note: the transformation of the domain names was done with `sed`, so it's consistent between the various reproduced files.

---

There is no `~/.ssh/config`, but here's the global one (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), shrunk for the sake of brevity:

```
$ grep -v '^#' /etc/ssh/ssh_config |grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

---

```
$ mtr pangolin
Name or service not known: Success
```

Comment: Could you post your `/etc/resolv.conf` and the output of this command `grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf` ?

Comment: @Awi: added it, plus a bit more.

Comment: Two questions 1) Does it work as intended if you use the fqdn? 2) Can you post the contents of ~/.ssh/config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config to see if there is any weirdness.

Comment: @PatrickRegan: I'll edit the requested stuff into the question. Yes, it works with the fqdn :) ... (will also adjust the question in that respect)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Do you see anything weird with `mtr pangolin` ?

Comment: @pl1nk: I'm not sure, it's equally weird as things before to me. Edited it into the question at the bottom.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem - did you ever find a solution? I noticed that if I do a 'ssh -v hostname' (-v is for verbose), then the ip address is wrong. For this server, we recently changed the IP. I've checked /etc/hosts, restarted nscd and done an nslookup and can't figure out where the old IP is coming from, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @jars99: afraid not. Never found a solution to this issue.

Comment: @jars99 I just solved a problem that sounds identical to the one you describe. `ping` and `ssh` were incorrectly resolving hostnames (rather than just failing to resolve altogether). I found that the `hosts: ` line my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` had `[NOTFOUND=return]` preceding `dns` in the list of sources. I think this was forcing the lookup command to return before the DNS servers were actually queried. After I moved `dns` in front of `[NOTFOUND=return]` on that line, `ssh` and `ping` started resolving hostnames correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whereas `ssh` and other programs such as `ping` use the glibc resolver to look up the host name ('pangolin' in this case), `host` looks the name up in DNS directly, bypassing the glibc resolver.  That's the difference.

However, given that the glibc resolver is, on your machine, configured to try `dns` after `files`, I can't explain why the resolver fails where `host` succeeds.

To try with the glibc resolver, one can use `getent hosts ...` in place of `host ...`.

I have seen this behavior reported before when dnsmasq was used as a local forwarding nameserver (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/998712) but you aren't using such a local nameserver; but perhaps the problem there and here wasn't in dnsmasq but in the glibc resolver.

Answer (score 11):

Your ssh may try to resolve IP6 and time out doing this. If you are not using IP6 try disabling IP6 in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` by changing AddressFamily from `any` to `inet`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I didn't notice before because all other servers I tried to connect to supported ipv6 already.

Comment: Hi, probably I have similar problem. I am using ipv4. I opened the `vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config` file but could not see the `AddressFamily`

Comment: @BiMo Then you can add it yourself. When it's not assigned a value it defaults to `any`.

Answer (score 5):

i got this error by putting a domain entry line before the 2 nameserver lines by accident.
nslookup worked. wget worked. ssh, scp, rsync failed.

moving domain to below nameservers and saving resolv.conf fixed. nothing else was necessary for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this a couple of times, and it always throws me until I remember the six domain restriction on the search list in resolv.conf.

Comment: 1. This is a very good point. The question text includes a listing of the resolv.conf file (although it appears to have been edited to anonymize the information). The file's `search` line contains more than six domain names. The glibc resolver only looks at the first six domains or 256 characters, whichever is less. I speculate that the `host` utility has no such restriction, and that `host` succeeds in resolving the name with the seventh or later domain name extention.

Comment: Note also that there should not be both a `dns-search` line and a `dns-domain` line in a single stanza in /etc/network/interfaces. The `dns-domain` option is actually deprecated; all search domain names should given be on the `dns-search` line.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an ancient question, but I'll add in what worked for me.

I had the same issue and found that in my `nsswitch.conf`, there was `mdns` in addition to `files` and `dns`.  Removing `mdns4` resolved this issue for me.

Comment: worked for me too - ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Except I already gave the contents of my `nsswitch.conf` and have mdns4 removed from the respective line.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing trouble accessing my sftp server. The ftp user was not able to loggin to sftp from another server. (Solaris - Openssh). I commented the "dns" entry in the nsswitch.conf and the issue resolved.